# Creating Filter Fields on Form Netsuite

Tags: filter, netsuite, custom-fields

I am trying to create filters using existing custom fields for a custom form on netsuite. For instance if I have an entity field called start date, I want to be able to filter the sublist on the form using this field as a filter. Is this possible ?

I'm still new to netsuite so please let me know if it is applicable without scripting or it needs a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a filter on a particular custom form using a SuiteScript. I don't think it can be done without using a script since there is no out of the box feature as such that I can think of. Also, please explain what do want to do with this filter. For eg. using the start date what data would you want to pull

Comment: I want to use these filter fields like start date or salary for example to filter a sublist displaying multiple custom records of employee. and their salaries. Can I create the filters using the existing entity fields like date or salary? or I cannot but create a filter from scratch and set its type.

Comment: Can you please answer me if there is a way I know I'm a beginner but I want to learn if it is feasible.

Comment: Sure, I would be glad if I can help in anyway. I am unable to understand what is purpose of creating this filter. Can you pls explain what do you mean by "multiple custom records of Employee". Employee record is a standard record in NetSuite of type 'entity'. Also,it would be great if you could add any screenshot by hiding all company related information